# Geolocation API doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, geolocation

I'm writing my web application on React/Redux. And I need to get user location with a help of Geolocation API. On desktop browsers everything works fine, but on mobile phones (checked out on Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 and iPhone 5s) it throws error code 1 - permission denied. And it doesn't requests any permissions to get the location.
[image]
[image]

Here's a test sample which I ran on my site:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            alert(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude);
        }, err => {
            alert('ERROR: ' + err.code);
        });
    } else {
        alert('Geolocation API is not supported!');
    }
}
```

What's the solution of this problem?

Comment: Did you check the OS and / or the browser settings to make sure geolocation was allowed either on the OS level or app level?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yep. [Here](https://html5demos.com/geo/) it throws permission request(alert window to accept/deny), but on my website it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure you havent accidently blocked your own site, once you hit block the request doesnt come back up till that setting is cleared

Comment: @PatrickEvans I opened site at the first time on the CloudFront and it also throws an error - permission denied

Answer (score 2):

Got the same Problem... Solved:

Check your phone permissions for sharing your location.

On iPhone:
Settings -> Location Services -> [your Browser]

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203033

*Added:*

Chrome requires https for geolocation usage:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: It's not only problem of the iOS... And everything is right with settings.

Comment: Ok. Another idea:
For some Browsers https is required when u want to use geolocation.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: Check out my comment under my question. CloudFront uses HTTPS for default.

Comment: Also this rule does't apply for localhost server.

Comment: Does your mobile browser uses adblocker?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't allow to get location for no reason. Maybe it's something wrong with combining React and Geolocation API

Answer (score 1):

As of the Year *2021*, this still does not work.

[image: Try to access location on mobile during react development]

[This is the link in that error message](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).
In case you're wondering, it talks about "prefer secure origins for powerful new features" and location is consider one of those powerful features.

To generate the above, update the `error` section as follows:

```js
  if (navigator.geolocation) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        // other
    },
    err => {
        // include the "code" part
        alert(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`)
    });
  };
```

- On **desktop** during development...
  It works because if you read from the above link you will note that `localhost` is considered a secure origin.

  In fact, even the chrome link shared in @chrisheyn's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621953/10849438), there is a section "[Does this affect local development?](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only#does_this_affect_local_development)" and explains why this should work on `locahost`.

---

- So how about **Mobile** during development?
  Notice that `react` serves the app over your network e.g. `http://192.168.0.134:3000` and that is definitely not considered a "secure origin" at all.

  This question "[Can I detect at runtime if the geolocation was blocked because of not being on a secure context](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only#can_i_detect_at_runtime_if_the_geolocation_was_blocked_because_of_not_being_on_a_secure_context)
  " mentions that... Errors due to this secure-context issue will return a `code` of 1 which is a "Permission Denied Error".

---

**What's the solution?**
Until the `react` team updates how your mobile picks the app during development, there is absolutely nothing you can to solve this issue.

To use the HTML5 Geolocation API, you will need to run the app over HTTPS. This means push your app to the cloud/host (in order to test this feature) or if you can some manage to get this network url `http://192.168.0.134:3000` to do `https` The latter option, i believe, is much harder but I'd be interested to know if someone pulls it off.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution. I'm using the Web Application Manifest and it needed to set the permission to use Geolocation API.

We just need to set an **"required_features"** option at *manifest.webapp* file:

```
{
  "required_features": ["geolocation"]
}
```

Hope it will be useful for somebody ;)